# Generate all dihedral transformations of a matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, function-construction, group-theory

Given a matrix, e.g.

```
matrix = Table[a[i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
```

I would like to have a function that takes `matrix` as input and returns a list of matrices representing all possible dihedral transformations of `matrix` (all possible simultaneous reflections and rotations along all columns and/or all rows). Of course I could write a monstrosity of `Do` routines, but I am wondering if there is a neat and quick way to do that in Mathematica? Thanks for any suggestion!

EDIT:

Forgot to mention: There should also be reflections (transposition) along the diagonal and anti-diagonal in the action of the group!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [`PermutationGroup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PermutationGroup) and [`Permute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permute). Here is a [`PermutationGroup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PermutationGroup) representation:

```
grp = PermutationGroup[{
    Cycles[{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}], Cycles[{{1,2},{4,5},{7,8}}], (*columns*)
    Cycles[{{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{3,6,9}}], Cycles[{{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}}], (*rows*)
    Cycles[{{2,4},{3,7},{6,8}}] (*rotations*)
}];
```

Then use [`Permute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permute) to get all of the transformations:

```
toMatrix[list_] := Partition[list, Sqrt[Length@list]]

Grid @ Partition[
    toMatrix /@ Permute[{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "q"}, grp],
    6
] //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{cccccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{h} & \text{q} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{h} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{a} & \text{c} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{f} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{q} & \text{h} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{a} & \text{c} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{q} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{f} & \text{e} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{a} & \text{d} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{e} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{f} & \text{q} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{a} & \text{d} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{f} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{e} & \text{h} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{a} & \text{g} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{h} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{q} & \text{f} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{a} & \text{g} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{q} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{h} & \text{e} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{b} & \text{a} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{d} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{g} & \text{q} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{b} & \text{a} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{g} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{d} & \text{f} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{b} & \text{c} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{f} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{q} & \text{g} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{b} & \text{c} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{q} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{f} & \text{d} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{b} & \text{e} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{d} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{f} & \text{q} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{b} & \text{e} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{f} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{d} & \text{g} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{b} & \text{h} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{g} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{q} & \text{f} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{b} & \text{h} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{q} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{g} & \text{d} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{c} & \text{a} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{d} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{g} & \text{h} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{c} & \text{a} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{g} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{d} & \text{e} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{c} & \text{b} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{e} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{h} & \text{g} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{c} & \text{b} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{h} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{e} & \text{d} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{c} & \text{f} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{d} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{e} & \text{h} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{c} & \text{f} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{e} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{d} & \text{g} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{c} & \text{q} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{g} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{h} & \text{e} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{c} & \text{q} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{h} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{g} & \text{d} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{d} & \text{a} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{b} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{c} & \text{q} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{d} & \text{a} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{c} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{b} & \text{h} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{h} & \text{q} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{h} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{d} & \text{f} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{c} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{q} & \text{h} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{d} & \text{f} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{q} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{c} & \text{b} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{d} & \text{g} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{h} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{q} & \text{c} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{d} & \text{g} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{q} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{h} & \text{b} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{e} & \text{b} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{a} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{c} & \text{q} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{e} & \text{b} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{c} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{a} & \text{g} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{e} & \text{d} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{a} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{g} & \text{q} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{e} & \text{d} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{g} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{a} & \text{c} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{e} & \text{f} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{c} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{q} & \text{g} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{e} & \text{f} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{q} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{c} & \text{a} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{e} & \text{h} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{g} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{q} & \text{c} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{e} & \text{h} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{q} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{g} & \text{a} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{f} & \text{c} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{a} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{b} & \text{h} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{f} & \text{c} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{b} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{a} & \text{g} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{f} & \text{d} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{a} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{g} & \text{h} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{f} & \text{d} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{g} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{a} & \text{b} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{f} & \text{e} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{b} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{h} & \text{g} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{f} & \text{e} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{h} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{b} & \text{a} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{f} & \text{q} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{g} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{h} & \text{b} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{f} & \text{q} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{h} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{g} & \text{a} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{g} & \text{a} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{b} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{c} & \text{f} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{g} & \text{a} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{c} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{b} & \text{e} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{g} & \text{d} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{e} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{f} & \text{c} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{g} & \text{d} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{f} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{e} & \text{b} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{g} & \text{h} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{g} & \text{h} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{g} & \text{q} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{c} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{f} & \text{e} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{g} & \text{q} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{f} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{c} & \text{b} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{h} & \text{b} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{a} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{c} & \text{f} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{h} & \text{b} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{c} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{a} & \text{d} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{h} & \text{e} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{d} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{f} & \text{c} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{h} & \text{e} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{f} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{d} & \text{a} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{h} & \text{g} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{a} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{d} & \text{f} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{h} & \text{g} & \text{q} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{d} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{a} & \text{c} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{h} & \text{q} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{c} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{f} & \text{d} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{h} & \text{q} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{e} & \text{f} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{b} & \text{c} & \text{a} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{q} & \text{c} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{a} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{b} & \text{e} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{q} & \text{c} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{b} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{a} & \text{d} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{q} & \text{f} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{d} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{e} & \text{b} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{q} & \text{f} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{h} & \text{e} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{d} & \text{a} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{q} & \text{g} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{a} & \text{b} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{d} & \text{e} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{q} & \text{g} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{d} & \text{e} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{a} & \text{b} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{q} & \text{h} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{b} & \text{a} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{e} & \text{d} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{q} & \text{h} & \text{g} \\
>  \text{f} & \text{e} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{c} & \text{b} & \text{a} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}$

Answer (score 2):

Let's denote a matrix by a simple notation:

```
M[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, q]
```

such that the matrix form is recovered by the substitution:

```
subM = {M[x__] :> MatrixForm[Partition[{x}, Sqrt[Length[{x}]]]]};
M[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, q] /. subM
```

> [image]

Rotations and reflections of rows is one dihedral group $D_{2n}$ with $2n$ elements. Rotations and reflections of columns is another copy of dihedral group $D_{2n}$. Finally, transposition along the diagonals (or, when combined with a row or column reflection, equivalently simply rotations by 90 degrees) are a superimposed $S_2$ group with 2 elements. This means we have a semi-direct product $S_2\rtimes D_{2n}$ with $2(2n)^2$ elements in total.

In our example $n=3$, so that we get $72$ elements. One can generate an invariant object from an `M` as follows:

```
invar[m_] := Block[{tmp, res, n, pref},
  pref = m /. M[xx__] -> 1;
  n = Sqrt[Length[m /. M -> List]];
  tmp = Partition[m/pref /. M -> List, n];
  res = Table[M[RotateRight[tmp, i]], {i, 0, n - 1}] //DeleteDuplicates;
  res = ((Table[ M[Transpose[RotateRight[Transpose[(#[[1]])], i]]], {i, 0, n - 1}] &) /@ res) // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates;
  res = {res, (Reverse@# & /@ # & /@ res)} // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates;
  res = {res, (Transpose@Reverse@Transpose@# & /@ # & /@ res)} // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates;
  res = {res, (Transpose@# & /@ # & /@ res)} // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates;
  pref ( res /. M[x__] :> (M[x] /. List -> Sequence) /. List -> Plus) // Expand
  ]
```

So that we properly get 72 distinct objects in the most general case, collectively furnishing an invariant set:

```
invar[M[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, q]] /. subM
```

> [image]

However, the function `invar[m_]` is too hacky for my taste. Especially when `n` grows bigger, I suspect it will become very slow. That is why I'd prefer to have a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

The action on the four corners of the matrix defines the group, so we are talking about DihedralGroup[4], which has 8 elements.

We can construct those 8 matrices combining Transpose and Reverse:

```
dih4[mat_] := With[{list = NestList[Transpose[Reverse[#]] &, mat, 3]}, Join[list, Transpose /@ list]]
```

Now try with your matrix:

```
MatrixForm /@ dih4[matrix]
```

Comment: Actually, I believe the group is $S_2\rtimes D_{2n}$. See my answer for details.

Comment: I misinterpreted what you meant by "reflections and rotations along all columns and/or all rows". You also seem to want swapping of columns and rows. (Compare for example the first two matrices in your list above.) Wouldn't that introduce factorials n! in the numbers of elements to account for all possible orders of columns, say?

Comment: It just so happens that the groups $D_{2n}$ and $S_n$ coincide for $n=3$, which means that the swapping that you refer to can always be expressed in terms of cyclic rotation and reflection when only three elements are present. And indeed $n!$ and $2n$ coincide for $n=3$. For $n>3$ no swapping will appear.